# String Array Max is only at 40

Tags: java, arrays, opencsv

my program was not able to get the index array of 41 it has error index array outbound it is separated by comma which is 41 commas when i did get the 40 i did not encounter the error but when it comes to 41 comma it give me an error index array outbound is there any limit in string array and hot maximize it.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(source1));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    String[] string = nextLine[0].split(",");
    System.out.println(string.length);
    if(string.length>=4){
        System.out.println(string[0]);
        System.out.println(string[1]);            
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You better check your lines of csv file very carefully, especially pay attention to empty character...  You can output **length** of nextLine to check and debug.

Comment: The first element of an array is numbered 0.  The 41st element is numbered 40.  The 42nd element is numbered 41.  Perhaps you only have 41 elements.

Comment: i have started the count to 0 when i print the 40 element it shown in the output the second to the last comma separated value so it means the last value should be 41 but when i print the 41 i got this error indexoutofbound

Comment: 058623434,015,,060,,023,,SOGO WAIST PINCHER BLACK S 0264                   ,,279.750,,1.00,044090,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,201558623434,A,170219,,null,02/19/2017,  /  /    ,               ,0000,    ,    ,  ,ADD,PC ,PC ,029,,,DSP,0,1      this the sample csv that im reading

Comment: You could use your debugger to inspect the value of `nextLine` before the call to `System.out.println`.

Comment: Hi Guys it turns out that my comma .split i'ts not working it only reads the first value

Comment: It seems like it does not continue to the second array by using split im getting indexarrayoutbound error what can you suggest to fix i tried checking the length first of array it print 1 although i have multiple values it means that the .split is not working can you guys enlighten with this one i tried searching in different threads the suggest using Regex but i'ts still no working

Answer (score 0):

If you hve 41 elements, in order to access the 41 element, you will request the 40 one from the array. Also, if you have 42 or more but you still got error accessing it, that means, it can be something wrong with the data in that element and you might get index out of bound error. Maybe you can put the content of the array.